# Mirror Modifier Collapsed in Centre

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I've being modelling a pelican with the mirror mode modifier when I came to apply the subdivision surface

I was horrified to discover the mirror modifier has collapsed inwards in the centre, this didn't happen previous when modelling a dinosaur, is there any way to fix this or do I have to start again? Appreciate any advice to help resolve this!
[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot to delete faces on the seam?

Comment: yeah delete the face. its causing the issue there

Comment: Yes! That was the issue! thanks so much to you both :))

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh