# Mirror Modifier Problems

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I did a project using mirror modifier, but I have 2 problems.

-There is a visible seam all around.[image]

- There is a huge gap at some places[image]

When I turn off subdivision modifier, there are no gap anymore
[image]

I tried to increase merge limit but, even 0.0001 don't do the right thing.
I succeed to merge some vertices by snapping and I checked merge and clipping. But the problems persist. Anybody could help?

Comment: Don't you have a face on the mirror plane?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh/23764#23764 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right/354#354

Comment: Thanks, indeed there were faces, I deleted them. But the problem on the first screen shot persists.